# Get the real color of the navigation bar

Tags: ios

For my app on iPhone X I need to create a footer. No problem here.

**BUT I need to put the same color as the navigation bar**.

The color of the navigationBar is set on barTintColor and cannot be changed.

The app builded, a UIVisualEffect is set automatically on the navigationBar and the color change : it's lighter.

**How can I get the color shown of the navigation bar?**

What I tried but didn't work :

- `footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor myColor]`
- `footer.tintColor = [UIColor myColor]`
- `footer.tintColor = navigationBar.barTintColor`
- `footer.backgroundColor = navigationBar.barTintColor`
- `imageView.image = [self.navigationController.navigationBar backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; [footer addSubview: imageView];`
- `UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
      blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
      UIVisualEffectView* visualView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
      [self.footer addSubview:visualView];`

**The code for the navigation bar : **

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = tintColor;

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIFont dpBoldFontWithSize:16.8],NSFontAttributeName,
  fontColor,NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
  nil]];
[self.navigationItem setTitle:title];
```

**The code for the footer **

```
  self.footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, kScreenHeight - 35, self.view.width, 35)];

    [self.footerView setBackgroundColor:color];
    [self.view addSubview:self.footerView];
```

**Screenshot of the problem :**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c9cj.png)

Comment: What about adding a UIVisualEffectView to your footer view ?

Comment: I tried with a blur effectStyleLight but no color change

Comment: Hm you are not setting the frame of your `visualView ` here. Can you add some code or context ?

Comment: I added a frame and the color didn't change

Comment: With navigationBar.isTranslucent = false ?

Comment: With navigationBar.isTranslucent = false my navbar seems darker but the footerView disapeared... there is no view anymore (see on debug view hierarchy)

Comment: Well check the frame of your `footerView`, `self.view.width` might be 0 or something

Comment: the frame of the footerView didn't change between no translucent and translucent; it's : frame = (0 777; 375 35). and it's not hidden... I can see it in the hierarchy list but not on the debug view... i'm going crazy...

Comment: Your view might out of the border of your view (777 is a bit high)

Comment: It's an iPhone X, the total height is 812, the footer is exactly where it has to be programmatically..

Comment: When translucent = false : https://imgur.com/0f1G5AC (the view selected is the footerView)

Comment: When `isTranslucent` is set to true, your view starts underneath the navigation bar (at least when using a storyboard)

Comment: When translucent = true : https://imgur.com/fMAiRab

Comment: "When isTranslucent is set to true, your view starts underneath the navigation bar (at least when using a storyboard)" Thank you that was that

Comment: I hope the designer will approuve the new color...

Comment: Have you tried to use AutoLayout instead of setting the frame by hand ?

Comment: This is a very old project so there is no storyboard...

Comment: You can still use constraints programmatically

Comment: Yes I can do that..

Comment: Or autoresizing maskn see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Or what about autoresizing mask ?

```
   UIView * footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 35, self.view.bounds.size.width, 35)];
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    footerView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    [self.view addSubview:footerView];
```